# AVAudioSession bug with play after remove app from task

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, background-process

I have some problems I init audio session and set this

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setActive:YES error:nil];
```

and

```
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

So my problem is when I play music in background then remove app from task (double click on home btn) and then I press play on headphone my app start play audio but I expected play default player (default player was playing before start my app)

Comment: You specifically asked the OS to send all remote control events to your app, hence it does so. If you want that to stop, you need to tell the OS to stop sending remote events.

Comment: Thanks its simple solution, I just was thinking in wrong way